# iphone slow navigation due to data load

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I'm newbie to objective-c . My problem is slow navigation between controllers.
When I jump from one controller to another it's really slow, because it gets data from the service, parse it and then display it. All this takes around 4-5 secs.
Now I've put all this data fetching in loadView of my DetailController. Is there anyway that I show the controller first and then display the data. Because as of now, when I select a row on my root controller, it shows activity and stays on root controller and then it navigates to the DetailController. 
So it loads the data first and then displays it. Is there anyway that I can reverse this process, show the controller first and then display it..

this is what I'm doing

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

DataCollection *collection = [DataCollection sharedObject];
Product *tempProduct = [[collection popularProducts] objectAtIndex:row] ;

ProductDetailViewController *tempProductDetail = [[ProductDetailViewController alloc] init];

tempProductDetail.homeViewProduct = tempProduct;
[tempProductDetail release];
}
```

and then the Detail Controller

```
- (void)loadView {
      [super loadView];
      // here's all the data loading and parsing ... which takes time
}
```

//Here's the method for downloading the data, I'm using a REST service to get all the data.

```
- (void) getProductData:(NSString*)productId{

NSMutableString *specificURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"GetProductPage?id="];
[specificURL appendFormat:@"%@",productId];
[specificURL appendFormat:@"&dataSources=&accountId=&companyId=&version=1&cultureCode=sv&currencyId=2&format=json"];

NSDictionary *serverCategories = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[appRequestController proceesRequest:specificURL]];
NSArray *categories = [[[serverCategories objectForKey:@"DataSources"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Items"];
[serverCategories release];

        if ([[productsArray objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"Name"]  != [NSNull null]) {
            [product setProductName:[[productsArray objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"Name"]];
        }
        else {
            [product setProductName:@""];
        }


        if ([[productsArray objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"ThumbnailImage"]  != [NSNull null]) {
            [product setProductImage:[[productsArray objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"ThumbnailImage"]];
        }
        else {
            [product setProductImage:@""];
        }


        if ([[productsArray objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"Price"]  != [NSNull null]) {

            [product setProductPrice:[[productsArray objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"Price"]];      
        }
        else {
            [product setProductPrice:@""];
        }

            [[collection popularProducts] addObject:product];
        [product release];
```

}

I've copy pasted junks of the code so that you can get an idea how I'm getting the data. Below is the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *MyIdentifier = @"mainMenuIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightstrip.png"]]];

}

UILabel *productNameLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 8, 200,10)];
[productNameLbl setText:[NSString stringWithString:[[[[DataCollection sharedObject] popularProducts]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] productName]]];
[productNameLbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]];

[cell addSubview:productNameLbl];
[productNameLbl release];

UILabel *productSubLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 22, 190,40)];
[productSubLbl setText:[NSString stringWithString:[[[[DataCollection sharedObject] popularProducts]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] productSubHeader]]];
[productSubLbl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:102/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
productSubLbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
productSubLbl.numberOfLines = 3;
[productSubLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10]];

[cell addSubview:productSubLbl];
[productSubLbl release];

NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
NSString *baseImageURL = @"http://samplesite.com/";
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithString:[[[[DataCollection sharedObject] popularProducts]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] productImage]];

[url appendString:baseImageURL];
[url appendString:imagePath];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 70, 70)];
[cell addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Are you loading the data synchronically?

Comment: Yes, for the above view. Have tried with Asynchronous calls as well but doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

Pass the url or product id to the detail view.  Inside the viewDidLoad of the ProductDetail, create a background thread to retrieve your data.  When you background thread finish, it will notify your ProductDetail controller with the detail.  At that time, you update your ProductDetailView.

To get your data on a background thread you can use

- [NSThread](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Don't use a thread, there's too much overhead and unnecessary setup. Use one of the asynchronous methods of `NSURLConnection`

Comment: The reason I like NSOperation, is that I can wrap all the code to deal with NSURLConnection in a neat list subclass.  NSURLConnection I will have to create delegates to my viewCOntroller.  THis way, with thew NSOperation subclass, I can use anywhere in my code with little overhead.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm confused here. How can I show the view first and then load the data ??? To me thread sounds like a good idea, I mean theoretically, this is what I'm looking for if I can load the data in a separate thread while I show the screen.

Comment: @donito, Edit your question with the method where you download the detail of the product and I will write a sample NSOperation subclass.

Comment: @black frog , I've edited the post and pasted some data from the function. I can also send you an PM with detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the row into your ProductDetailViewController, and do the fetch in it's viewDidLoad method.  You might also want to show a spinner (UIActivityIndicator), and you definitely should read up on background threads.

Comment: this is what I did, but doesn't work on background thread... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804207/iphone-background-thread-not-working-properly

Answer (score -1):

To make view available to user and loading data after some time you can use NSTimer.

Just have a NSTimer method which will be called in viewDidLoad method as

> - [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:<#(NSTimeInterval)ti#> target:<#(id)aTarget#> selector:<#(SEL)aSelector#> userInfo:<#(id)userInfo#> repeats:<#(BOOL)yesOrNo#>]

put some time interval which will be calling your loading method after that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @kubi If you are loading heavy data like images you can call them afterwards and show rest of the textual data fetched from services which will be fast compare to images in that case this would be useful. can you please assist me what is wrong with that ?

Comment: Why would you use a timer at all? Why not just download the image asynchronously and display it when it's finished?

Comment: @kubi , I've another problem with loading it asynchronously. It shows me the images which are on the screen, and when I scroll down and come back up again ,the images are gone and are fetched again. Is there any way I can store the images that are already fetched so that loaded images don't need to load again.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're doing the image loading in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? The best thing to do is probably move the image downloading code into `viewWillLoad` and make sure you're only using cached images in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Kubi , I'm getting all the data in the same service call. There's no way that I can send another call just to get the images, that isn't feasible and possible. Please tell me how can I separate the images and put them in the viewWillLoad. I've edited my post and pasted the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath . Please advise.

Comment: Take a look at your code. You're making one call to get the image URL in `getProductData` and another call to download the image in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You should move all that logic into asynchronous web requests.

Comment: @Kubi, thanks , but how do I do that to make it Asynchronous. And also I've another problem with this code, when I scroll up and down the data in the tables gets messy, it overlaps the existing data. How can I fix that too. Please help.

Comment: @donito For help making your table view more responsive, look at Apple's example project: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: For help making your tableview work correctly, that's probably best moved into a new question.