# iphone, background thread not working properly

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I want to display the view first and then load the data in a background thread. When I navigate from root controller to the view controller, I want to display the view first. As of now, it stays on the root controller until the view controller is loaded. Here's my code for the root controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
ProductDetailViewController *tempProductDetail = [[ProductDetailViewController alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tempProductDetail animated:YES];

[tempProductDetail release];
}
```

ProductDetailViewController, here I want to display the view first and then load the data...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(workerThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void) workerThread{

NSAutoreleasePool *arPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
[arPool release];
}
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please, help.

Comment: performSelectorOnMainThread does not create a new thread.detachNewThreadSelector will create a new thread.

Comment: doing this 

 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(workerThread) toTarget: self  withObject: nil];

shows me an error.....bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x664e200: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer for this issue,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(workerThread) withObject:nil];
}

- (void) workerThread
{
// Set up a pool for the background task.
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// only do data fetching here, in my case from a webservice.
//...

// Always update the components back on the main UI thread.
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

[pool release];
}

// Called once the background thread task has finished.
- (void) displayView
{
//here in this method load all the UI components
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use   `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(workerThread) withObject:nil];` instead of

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(workerThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: by using this method , it shows me this error


 bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x6232b10: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
[Switching to process 19034]
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the following pattern instead for threading, in my opinion it's much cleaner:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
   NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] 
                                       initWithTarget:self 
                                       selector:@selector(someFunction) 
                                       object:nil];
   [[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addObject:operation]; // this will actually start the thread
   [operation release];
}

- (void)someFunction 
{
   // don't need to initialize and release an autorelease pool here,
   // you can just write a function as usual ...

   [self updateUI];
}

- (void)updateUI 
{
   if (![NSThread isMainThread]) // if we need a UI update, force it on main thread
   {
      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
      return;
   } 

   // do UI updates here
}
```

By writing code in this way, you can more dynamically decide which function you want to thread, since there is no autorelease pool requirement. If you need to do UI updates, the *updateUI* function will make sure for itself that it's running on the main thread, so the caller doesn't need to take this into account.